# Why does getByRole not find a button with aria-label?

Tags: javascript, button, wai-aria

I have a use case (a modal dialog) for a button with a hidden label that uses an icon as its content. It's essentially the same use case as [described here](https://www.w3.org/TR/WCAG20-TECHS/ARIA14.html) in Example 1:

```
<button aria-label="Close" onClick={() => doSomething()}><svg>...</svg></button>
```

(I just have an SVG element as a child of the button instead of the text "X".)

When I execute this query:

```
screen.getByRole('button', { name: 'Close' });
```

the button isn't found. The debug output tells me that this button's name is "". Yet the [documentation](https://testing-library.com/docs/dom-testing-library/api-queries#byrole) states, "You can query the returned element(s) by their accessible name. The accessible name is for simple cases equal to e.g. the label of a form element, or the text content of a button, **or the value of the aria-label attribute**." (emphasis mine)

I found that [this example](https://developers.google.com/web/fundamentals/accessibility/semantics-aria/aria-labels-and-relationships#aria-label) also supports my use case.

So why does `getByRole('button', {name: 'Close'})` -- or even the simpler `getByLabelText('Close')` for that matter -- not find this button element?

Comment: It works fine. Can't reproduce.

Answer (score 1):

Well, I guess this happens to all of us. The fact I had to edit this question right after posting for writing "aria" wrong TWICE should've been a good indication of the root cause, that being that I had written `<button arial-label="Close">...</button>`. Yep. "Arial" is a valid word, so spellchecker never catches it either.  I need to write an ESLint rule or something; happens too often.

So this DOES work:

```
getByLabelText('Close')
```

or

```
getByRole('button', {name: 'Close'})
```

Sorry for the not-so-great question.

Comment: Still, I had the exact same issue, and after reading this I checked my spelling... Doh